# install plugins manually?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

is it possible to install and uninstall plugins manually in grails??
if yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 6):

If the commands are failing for some reason, you can remove them by:

1. delete the entry for the plugin from application.properties
2. delete the plugin folder from ~/.grails/*grails version*/projects/*project name*/plugins

Comment: Only if your not using an IDE such as STS on Windoz, in which caase you may need to shut it down to remove the files in step 2

Comment: True, IDE's may lock the plugin JARs.

Answer (score 3):

For Grails 2.x, that's what the

```
grails install-plugin <plugin>
```

and

```
grails uninstall-plugin <plugin>
```

commands are for. See the command line reference at http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/.

Comment: It should be mentioned, that it works only for Grails 2.x. For Gradle 3.x, it can be installed by manually editing the file `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 3):

(Grails 2.2.4) To add a plugin that exists for example in your ***grails-project-dir\lib\the-grails-plugin-0.1.zip*** directory. Edit your ***grails-project-dir\grails-app\BuildConfig.groovy*** to include the following

```
plugins {
  // ....
  compile "lib:the-grails-plugin:0.1"
}
```

This will update your ivy-cache with folder called lib\the-grails-plugin

e.g: **[user-home]\.grails\ivy-cache\lib\the-grails-plugin**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this is an old question, but it's probably a good idea to say here that since Grails 2.0, the best way to install a plugin is to update `BuildConfig.groovy`, adding it in the plugins section:

```
    plugins {
        // ....
        compile ":console:1.2"
    }
```

The scripts for installing/uninstalling plugins are deprecated and will likely be removed because they have issues regarding scopes and transitive dependencies.

If you want to install a plugin that is not in the central repositories, you can install the plugin in your Maven cache with [`grails install`](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/ref/Command%20Line/maven-install.html) and then you'll be able to use it in your applications the same way.